# Prevent Encoding when converting to byte Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have a controller that is building using a `StringBuilder` called `param` to create a string to post to a `REST` service.  The string that is passed is a query string that will get parsed.  I'm encoding the values for each pair so that ampersands, doesn't inadvertantly create a new key.

An encoded `param` string might look like

```
clientType=MyClient&form_id=webform_client_form_38&referrer=http://mywebsite&company=My+%26+Company
```

Here is the code I'm using to send to the `REST` service

```
byte[] formData = UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(param.ToString());
req.ContentLength = formData.Length;

//Send the request:
using (Stream post = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    post.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
}
```

When I debug the `REST` service the string is always encoded back, adding the ampersand back between My and Company.

Is there another built in method that will convert the string to a `byte` without encoding the text?

Comment: You seem to be confusing HTML/URL decoding and string->binary encoding. They're very different, and you need to separate them in your mind. Also, `UTF8Encoding.Default` actually means `Encoding.Default`, which is a platform-specific default encoding - not a good idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet how would you convert it to bytes?  I also found that the REST service was actually encoding it before passing it on to my WCF service which is what was causing the issue

Comment: I'd probably use `Encoding.UTF8`, having ensured I specified the encoding in headers. However, the important part is that the ampersand between My and Company has *nothing* to do with the string -> binary encoding. It's because you're using a form encoding, and logically the value you're specifying *is* "My & Company". It's entirely correct for the REST infrastructure to perform that peice of decoding for you.

Comment: Thanks @Jonskeet I do see the separation. the binary encoding is just changing the string to a byte array, it doesn't care what's in it. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a HTML Decode function? that will transform back the string to the correct string that you sent.

HttpUtility.HtmlDecode